# Laptop is not booting

Tags: hard-drive, boot

When i switch on my laptop(Samsung np-r540) it just only show a blinking cursor. I tried to boot it via an external hdd which has ubuntu installed in it. I can view contents of my primary hdd from ubuntu. My primary hdd contains ubuntu and windows 7. All system files are preserved but when I do normal booting it just shows a blinking cursor.

The laptop was working properly and I was switching from a video to another suddenly a small sound was heard from inside and it was there until I turned of the laptop by pressing power button. From here ownwards my laptop is like this.

I am asking for a way to make it boot without reinstalling it. All contents are there in the hdd, as I can see it from ubuntu in external hdd.

Comment: You tried rewriting GRUB?

Comment: I didn't do that let me try. Can you provide a reference to it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume there is nothing wrong with the hardware at this stage as, as you've said, managed to boot into Ubuntu and look at your internal HDD. Are you able to get into Safe Mode or Windows Recovery (tap F8 at POST)?

I suspect the bootloader may have got corrupted. If you're able to get into Recovery or Safe mode you will be able to perform a 'chkdsk /f /x'. Try a chkdsk first if you can, if that doesn't work then we'll look at repairing the MBR/Bootloader.

Comment: its linux + windows....he'll have to write GRUB....windows bootloader does not recognize linux

Comment: There isn't any recovery or safe mode options

Answer (score 0):

If your hard drive is broken (might be the noise), try removing the hard drive before trying to boot off the USB.

If you have an ipod classic plugged into it, that also somehow prevents my laptop from booting properly. Most other external drives do this, too. I recommend a USB stick. Detatch the external HDD while booting from USB stick, then plug the HDD back in after it successfully starts booting.

If neither of these work, some USB sticks have caused this. Try using a different make / model of USB drive. The old SanDisk cruzers work well, and most PNY drives, while slower, work as well. I have had some success with the cruzer Glides, too.

If none of these work, try replacing your RAM.

Comment: Valid point. If there are any USB hard drives of any kind your computer may try booting from one of those first. Verify your boot order in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a noise that was heard from you laptop before it stopped working, do test the hard drive. each HDD manufacturer has their own testing software that is downloadable from their website and can be burned to a CD. It is bootable, and will test your drive.

I have replaced many a drive that was bad enough to not boot, but in good enough shape to read the data. Take this time to use your live CD to pull you data onto a back up. A worthwhile effort in any case.